# how to store web application settings

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm developing laravel application and I want to know what is best practice to save setting information in database?

for example, I want to save `email`, `phone`, `working hour`, `facebook`, `Instagram`, `github`,... accounts

my first solution was to create a table with columns for each setting and create one row and fill data in it, I'm wondering can I do this in a more clean and neat way?

Comment: Hi, I think it's correct to use a table to store this settings, or you could also use a .ini file given Laravel offers an easy way to manage .ini files.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very normal way to solve this problem, and would certainly qualify as "best practice".

If you will be storing information about the users *of your laravel site*, you may want to use one of the preexisting packages which does most of this for you such as [Laravel-Users](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-users) (or the prebuilt [Laravel-Auth](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth)).

Do be sure not to store secret information such as a user's passwrods unencrypted in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple way to store system application's information into the database. just create a migration or table of "settings" and make the views and collect system application data by form from user and store into the "settings" table. Now, you need to complete the CRUD of it. Thanks